# Value from input element is not properly working in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

Jsfiddle Link: https://jsfiddle.net/gzp0pcot/

I have an input element with id "myTextBox"

I want to change the slider value as I change the value in this input box.
So I am using Jquery which triggers a function when anything is changed/pasted on that input box.

```
$("#ex1").slider('setValue',this.value);
```

Above statement should change the slider value and position. If I pass integer value directly, it works but it is not working for current input element value.
Below statement works and changes slider position:

```
$("#ex1").slider('setValue',578);
```

Also current input element value is working if I use alert() function.
And if I change the value of "val" variable manually, then also the slider changes its position but current value is not reflected.

I am using Bootstrap slider from :
https://github.com/seiyria/bootstrap-slider

I also tried below statements to get current value , which I suppose are equivalent to above method I am using i.e. `this.value`  :

```
var val = documentgetElementById("#myTextBox").value;
var val = $(this).val();
var val = $("$myTextBox").val();
```

But no luck with this too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap `this.value` into `parseInt` to force it being viewed as an integer.

```
parseInt(this.value, 10);
```

updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gzp0pcot/3/

Comment: Thank you. And by default was that variable acting as string ?

Comment: By default is was. Try `typeof(this.value)`.